# Event on: Create Document Library

Tags: document-library, event-receivers

After the creation of a Document Library I need to execute some things, like:

- add a Content Type
- add a Workflow to the library
- may be other stuff

These things should be executed automatically.

I could write a *Farm Solution* to implement this requirement. But `EventReceiver` are only working on already existing `lists`. Is there another approach?

We are using SharePoint 2013 on premise.

Thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should look into SPListEventReceiver.ListAdding https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splisteventreceiver.listadding.aspx for this. You have to register this event on every web, but than you can do what you're trying to do.

Maybe you have to use asynchronous event, I'm not sure about that.